# How can I adjust the color of an html element based on a certain js value smoothly and efficiently?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little simulation where grass turns a different color based on it's energy level.  Currently every grass bock goes through an if/else statement to determine what color it is every gameloop.  making enough if statements to make the colors change smoothly seems very cpu intensive, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this.

simulation can be found here:  http://j.mp/Wou7Sl
(the part about coloring the grass is a function called colorGrass started @ line 134)

This isn't an urgent question or anything, but an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: jQuery UI or a color animation plugin will let you smoothly animate colors.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are some things you can do to significantly improve performance.

- You have a lot of unnecessary calls to `$(document).ready`; these will just slow things down.
- jQuery selectors are notoriously slow compared to `getElementById`; use that instead where performance matters, and try to look up elements as little as possible. Get a handle to the element and reuse it.
- `.style` is much faster than jQuery's `.css`, use it when performance matters.
- Avoid repeatedly referencing `foo[bar]`; instead, do `baz = foo[bar]` and then use `baz`.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JurfJ/) with some of the changes described above; you'll notice that it runs more smoothly, consumes less CPU, and can run at higher frame rates. There are more optimizations to be made, but you get the idea.

Now that we've cleaned that up, we can tackle the grass. Your grass code originally looked like this:

```
function colorGrass(i) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (Grasses[i].energy < 25) {
            $('#' + Grasses[i].id + '').css('background-color', '#666600');
        }
        if (Grasses[i].energy > 25 && Grasses[i].energy < 50) {
            $('#' + Grasses[i].id + '').css('background-color', '#669900');
        }
        if (Grasses[i].energy > 50 && Grasses[i].energy < 75) {
            $('#' + Grasses[i].id + '').css('background-color', '#66cc00');
        }
        if (Grasses[i].energy > 75) {
            $('#' + Grasses[i].id + '').css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    });
}
```

After making the changes mentioned above, it looks something like this (cleaner, don't you think?):

```
function colorGrass(i) {
    var grass = Grasses[i];
    var el = document.getElementById(grass.id);
    if (grass.energy < 25) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#666600';
    }
    else if (grass.energy < 50) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#669900';
    }
    else if (grass.energy < 75) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = '#66cc00';
    }
    else {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
}
```

Now, to get the grass to gradiate smoothly, you should be able to take the "energy" value and translate it directly to the "green" channel, for example:

```
function colorGrass(i) {
    var grass = Grasses[i];
    var el = document.getElementById(grass.id);
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(100,' + (grass.energy + 100) + ',0)';
}
```

How it should look exactly is up to you, so tweak these values as you see fit, and make any other changes you need to make (css, etc.) to make it look good.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.  I didn't know that so many JQuery functions were so slow, nor did I know about rgb.  Seems like Stack overflow is really helpful for newbie programmers like me...

Comment: yeah, I've updated the code so it now does not use much JQuery, and runs much faster.